# how to denormalize data on a dataframe on spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I have a peculiar requirement to denormalize data like below:

Source dataframe: `Key, item_desc`

Target dataframe: `Key, item_desc1, item_desc2, item_desc3, item_desc4`

for every 4 records on source dataframe I should create one record on target dataframe.

source data:

```
Key, item_desc
1, desc1
1, desc2
1, desc3
1, desc4
1, desc5
1, desc6
```

target data:

```
key, item_desc1, item_desc2, item_desc3, item_desc4
1, desc1, desc2, desc3, desc4
1, desc5, desc6
```

Can anyone guide me on how to write this code?
I have done a sample code to do it on scala like below:

```
var l = (1 to 102).toList
var n = ""
var j = 1
for (i <- l){
n = n + l(j) + ","
if (j%4 == 0) {
println(n)
n = ""
}
if (j+1 == l.size) println(n)
j = j+1
}
```

But, I should apply this logic to dataframe/rdd/list.

Please help me on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val w = Window.partitionBy("key").orderBy("item_desc")

val df = Seq(
  (1, "desc1"), (1, "desc2"), (1, "desc3"), 
  (1, "desc4"), (1, "desc5"), (1, "desc6")
).toDF("key", "item_desc")

df
  // Add sequential id for group 0 .. n - 1
  .withColumn("id", row_number.over(w) - 1)
  // Add row group id
  .withColumn("group_id", floor($"id" / 4))
  // Add column group id 
  .withColumn("column_id", concat(lit("item_desc"), $"id" % 4))
  .groupBy("key", "group_id")
  .pivot("column_id")
  .agg(first("item_desc"))
  .drop("group_id").show
// +---+----------+----------+----------+----------+
// |key|item_desc0|item_desc1|item_desc2|item_desc3|
// +---+----------+----------+----------+----------+
// |  1|     desc1|     desc2|     desc3|     desc4|
// |  1|     desc5|     desc6|      null|      null|
// +---+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

but unless number of values associated with a single key is small, it won't scale well, so use at your own risk.

Comment: Wow, thats great! Thanks much! I was thinking of a solution using ListBuffer, for loop, etc. But you solved it using a dataframe. Amazing. Thank you :)